# Community bulletinが表示されていない

Tags: バグ, 完了

英語版ではメイン、メタの両方で、右のサイドバーに「コミュニティ掲示板」が表示されます。

[image: 英語版のやつ]

日本語版では表示されていないようにみえます。現状だと、[注目](/questions/tagged/%e6%b3%a8%e7%9b%ae)な質問が日の目を見る場がありません。

追記: 英語の記事が混在する状態で表示させたらどうなるかの例:

[image: モックアップ]

Answer (score 1):

Community Bulletinに3つのリンクがあります：

1. 新ブログの記事（英語のみ）
2. Meta.SEの注目ポスト（英語のみ）
3. 当サイトのメタポスト（日本語）

英語が目立つ所にあまりよくないと思って、とりあえずCommunity Bulletin全体をオフにしました。

オンはできますが、英語が目の前にありますし、Community Bulletin自体がかなり新しい機能です。

オンにするべきですか？するなら、どの形がいいですか？（英語を含めても大丈夫ですか？）

Comment: 「オンにするべき」に一票: 運営・運用に関する話題をさっと確認できるので、ベータ初期にこそオンになっていてほしい機能です。英語を含めても大丈夫かは、私は自信をもった判断ができません。質問本文に表示例を追加してみました: サイドバーという、メインの導線からは外れた位置にあるので、英語のコンテンツに興味がない人は視界処理回路が自動的に無視してくれるのでは、と期待しますが...