# Meta Stack Exchangeでの注目記事をサイドバーに表示したい

Tags: 機能の要求, 完了

Stack Exchange ネットワークにはスタック・オーバーフロー以外にいくつもサイトがあります。特に、それらのサイトに共通した問題を扱うメタとして [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) (MSE) というサイトが存在します。

ところで、英語版 Stack Overflow などの英語系 Stack Exchange サイトでは、サイドバーの「メタでのおすすめ (Featured on Meta)」に「そのサイトのメタでの [注目](/questions/tagged/%e6%b3%a8%e7%9b%ae) 質問」と「MSE での [注目](/questions/tagged/%e6%b3%a8%e7%9b%ae) 質問」が両方表示されます。（ただしタグは英語では [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) です。）

[image: 英語版 Stack Overflow の Featured on Meta のスクリーンショットです。MSE の featured な投稿と MSO の featured な投稿が両方表示されています。]

<sup>（↑英語版 Stack Overflow でのスクリーンショット）</sup>

現在日本語版スタック・オーバーフローの「メタでのおすすめ」欄には、日本語版メタの記事しか表示されていません。しかし個人的には日本語版においても MSE での投稿を宣伝する価値があると思っています。そこで、日本語版スタック・オーバーフローのサイドバーにも MSE の注目質問を表示するようにしたいです。いかがでしょうか？

- メリット

  - Stack Exchange ネットワーク全体で盛り上がっている話題について日本語版からも導線が作れる。
  - Meta Stack Exchange 自体を知ってもらえる。
- デメリット

  - 和訳予定の無い英語記事へリンクすることになる。

追記：表示したい方は upvote して頂けると幸いです。[aki さんの回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3021/19110)もご覧ください。

---

To the Community Team:

Is there any reasons not to show MSE's [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) posts on the SOja's "Featured on Meta"? If there is no reasons and SOja's community also accepts this feature request, is it possible to show them on SOja?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2020年7月29日から設定が変わり、表示されるようになりました。

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[プライベートベータ版時代に「英語が目立つ所にあるのはあまりよくない」という理由からCommunity Bulletin 全体がオフにされた](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/210/14055)ようです。

オンに切り替えることはできるようですが、@nekketsuuuさんが言われた通り、和訳予定の無い英語記事へのリンクが表示されることになります。

尚、他言語サイト(SOes, SOpt, SOru)では Community Bulletin は表示されております。

2014年10月の時点ではオンに切り替えたいというお声が少なかったようです。今ぜひ表示して欲しいと思われる方は、@nekketsuuuさんの（上の ↑ ）ご投稿にプラス投票をお願いいたします！

Comment: 質問にプラス投票すれば良いですか？

Comment: そうですね、質問の方でいきましょう

Comment: 和訳されなくても、単語を拾い読みして気になるスレッドがあればMETAに「訳して！」依頼もありなのかな？と思いました。