# サイドバーに表示される「メタでのおすすめ」の文言を見直したい

Tags: 討議, 完了

メインサイトのサイドバーに「メタでのおすすめ」が表示されますが、この文言を見直したいです。

原文は "Featured on Meta" で、Meta Stack Exchange の投稿が表示されますが…

- "Featured" を "おすすめ" と訳すのに違和感があります。実際には "注目の" や "話題の" といったニュアンスの方が実態に近い気がします。
- カタカナで「メタ」と訳してしまうと、「日本語版のメタ」と区別が付かないです。
  元の "on Meta" も正直イケてないですが、"MSE (Meta Stack Exchange) の" という事が分かるようにしたいです。

とは言え、すぐ下の「今話題のメタ投稿」との兼ね合いも考慮しないとこちらもややこしい事になりそうで悩ましいです。

**現在の表示例:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**関連:**
[Meta Stack Exchangeでの注目記事をサイドバーに表示したい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3020/3060)

Answer (score 4):

この部分、SOja Meta で [注目](/questions/tagged/%e6%b3%a8%e7%9b%ae) タグが付いた質問も載るので、言葉遣いを合わせて「注目のメタ投稿」に訳を変えるのは如何でしょうか。

---

[完了](/questions/tagged/%e5%ae%8c%e4%ba%86)

追記@2023/01/10
サイトへの反映を確認しました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]